# WebBrowser Url to string not work

Tags: c#

When the code reaches `MessageBox.Show()` it throws an exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Here is my code:

```
WebBrowser webb = new WebBrowser();    
webb.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://facebook.com&access_token=" + Settings.Default["token"].ToString());

MessageBox.Show(webb.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
```

Do you see a reason why this might be the case ?

Comment: Could you tell please which exactly line of code throws this exception?

Comment: Set a breakpoint, and see where you're trying to access an object or a property that is null.

Comment: line error messagebox MessageBox.Show(webb.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());

Comment: @Federal09, I've got guess `Url` property could be null while browser's navigation is not completed.

Comment: @Federal09, I'd suggest you might try subscribe to `OnNavigated` or `OnDocumentCompleted` event and access to the `Url` property in the handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
WebBrowser webb = new WebBrowser();

private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    webb.Url = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://facebook.com&access_token=" + Settings.Default["token"].ToString());
    webb.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);        
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(webb.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
}
```